# I'm trying to authorize in PostMan, but it gives me "Request method 'GET' not supported"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman

I'm trying firstly just output the dates from POST method in '/login' cause I'm not sure the correctness of my code. I hope you will help me, thanks.

**MainController.java**

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials) {
        return "username: " + credentials.getUsername() + " password: " + credentials.getPassword();
    }
}
```

**PostMan query**

```
[![Postman dropdown list][1]][1]

[Screenshot link, if there is no picture above][1]

{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
```

I've tried send dates as a row (JSON) and as form, but in anyway it gives me these error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-29T10:03:20.711+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

I notice, that in compiler throws me this error **"org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
"**, after that gave me this **"Request method 'GET' not supported"**

Comment: If you aim to create a simple application that takes as a parameter a JSON object and returns a response. Include in your pom.xml only spring boot web dependency, and then proceed with the given answers below.  
If you want to go further and create a login module, then spring-security is a good way to start your journey. I recommend you start with a tutorial for beginners. There are many great ones, such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm-8qfMWEV8&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTYTEooakHchTGglSvkZAjnE) from Koushik Kothagal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in answers, selecting the POST method from the dropdown in Postman will help with the following error:

```
"Request method 'GET' not supported."
```

Then you will face the error below:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-28T16:54:55.288+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.example.demo.controller.MainController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

To solve this, you should slightly modify the endpoint:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials) {
        return "username: " + credentials.getUsername() + " password: " + credentials.getPassword();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Credentials {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private Credentials() {
    }

    // getters and setters omitted, make sure you have them.
}
```

- `@RequestBody` annotation expects a JSON object to deserialize. It is necessary to have an object available for mapping.
- Because you are using `@RestController` annotation, there is no need for `@ResponseBody` above the method. It is already [included](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html).

Comment: I've updated my code and provided screenshot of my postman above. Also i've founded that this mistake common thing to users of Spring Boot and there was code how avoid the error "method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}", after it this error has gone, but there is new error "Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.example.demo.controller.MainController.login(com.example.demo.model.GlobalVar.Credentials)"

Comment: It looks like you are referencing in your parameters to Credentials class but have implemented some GlobalVar along the way. Fix it in the method parameters according to your implementation. The error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick "POST" method from the METHOD dropdown:

[image]

Comment: I've selected POST, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a screenshot of postman ? because i think you didn't choose "POST" from the dropdown list next to the URL. it should be GET by default

Comment: I've selected POST, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try request body x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: The same mistake "Request method 'GET' not supported"

Answer (score 0):

In some reasons in front of MainController there is must be "@RequestMapping()", it works for me

Answer (score 0):

try @RequestBody(required=false)
or mentioned request body x-www-form-urlencoded